# parse localtime in c++

Tags: c++, ctime

Is there an easy "beginner" way to take the current time using `<ctime>` to a Date object that has

```
int month
int day
int year
```

for it's member variables? Thanks.

Comment: By "standard Date object" do you mean `time_t`?

Comment: read about localtime here: http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
time_t tt = time(NULL); // get current time as time_t
struct tm* t = localtime(&tt) // convert t_time to a struct tm
cout << "Month "  << t->tm_mon 
     << ", Day "  << t->tm_mday
     << ", Year " << t->tm_year
     << endl
```

The `tm` struct ints are all 0-based (0 = Jan, 1 = Feb) and you can get various day measures, day in month (`tm_mday`), week (`tm_wday`) and year(`tm_yday`).

Answer (score 2):

If there is localtime_r then you should use **localtime_r** rather than localtime since this is the reentrant version of localtime.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    time_t tt = time(NULL); // get current time as time_t
    tm  tm_buf;
    tm* t = localtime_r(&tt, &tm_buf); // convert t_time to a struct tm

    std::cout << "Month "  << t->tm_mon
              << ", Day "  << t->tm_mday
              << ", Year " << t->tm_year
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```